# To fetch the form results from an external website on the same page

Tags: php, curl

I have this code that works perfectly. But, after I submit it, I'm redirected to the external website, where results can be seen. Instead, I want the results to be displayed on the same website. I'm open to to all kinds of suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line should be:

```
echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] . '" method="post">
```

Then above your last line where you echo, put this:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Also, change your location line to this:

```
$location = 'http://results.vtu.ac.in/vitavi.php';
```

-----EDIT-----

I added some code to parse the response for you, final code would be:

```
<?php

echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] . '" method="post">
<input type="text" name="rid">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&(!empty($_POST['rid'])))
{
    $location = 'http://results.vtu.ac.in/vitavi.php';

    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $location );

    $post_array = array(
        "rid" => $_POST['rid'],
        "submit" => "submit"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $start = '<TD width="513">';
    $end = '<br>';

    $response = strstr($response, $start);
    $end = stripos($response, $end);
    $response = substr($response, strlen($start), $end - strlen($start));

    echo $response."<br/>";
}  

?>
```

Comment: Nope , doesn't seem to work i have uploaded to my site you can check i tried your code replacement , www.enggnetwork.com/awesome.php and value you can enter is "1nc09cs065" that is my university roll. number.

Comment: Made another edit, you need to change your $location line as well.  Instead of just outputting the $response you'll probably want to use some string methods to extract what you're looking for from the HTML, but if you need help with that you should start another thread.

Comment: Added some code to parse the response out so you're not displaying all of their HTML.  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: that works like charm :) , thanks alot :) !! i m so delighted , finally got the results script in my website , thanks to you  ! there's 1 more website  www.fastvturesults.com here his mechanism is awesome he fetches the result from university and stores results in new html file for each and every roll number ! thats pretty coll. thanks alot :) and do you know about the methodology that is used in that site ?

Comment: Can you click the check mark next to my answer to mark it as accepted so others know the problem is solved.  Glad it worked out for you.  It's hard to say what he's doing because I don't know the system, but if you can get a huge list of ID numbers in a file, you could loop through the file doing the CURL function and storing the response in a database along with the roll number.

Comment: ohh thanks , alot , thats something that i can start with  :) sorry i didn know about ticking , i'm new to this.